# Typescript file will not compile when I build solution (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

When I try to build my solution in Visual Studio 2012, the javascript file is not generated. It only happens for a specific file.

Comment: If you delete the file and create it again through VS that will probably fix the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem for me was that the file's Build Action was set incorrectly.

Go to the file's properties and make sure that it is set to TypeScriptCompile.

[image: File Properties: TypeScriptCompile]

Answer (score 2):

I found that for a fresh project my .csproj file was missing some important lines - no idea why, but easy fix which I talk about it a bit [in my TypeScript blog](http://keyoti.com/blog/sick-of-javascript-intro-to-typescript-visual-studio-setup/):

...despite the “Build Action” for the .ts file being correctly set to “TypeScriptCompile”.  To fix this I had to

Right click on the project in solution explorer and choose Unload Project
Right click the project and choose Edit 
Add the bold lines from the code below in their relevant sections

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=”‘$(Configuration)’ == ‘Debug'”>

<TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>

<TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>

<TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>

<TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>

</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=”‘$(Configuration)’ == ‘Release'”>

<TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>

<TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>

<TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>

<TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>

</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project=“$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets” />
```

The import line should go towards the end of the project file where other Import elements appear.  After making this change my .ts files compiled properly.  It would appear to me that this bug was taken care of in subsequent releases of TypeScript as it is not a problem with Visual Studio 2013 and TS 1.4.

Right click on the project in the solution explorer and reload the project.

Answer (score 1):

Install Web Essentials http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

It has a setting for compile on build: 
[image]

Comment: As of Web Essentials 3.0, all TypeScript support has been removed.  More info here: http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Essentials-2013-Where-is-the-TypeScript-support.aspx

Comment: ProVega's Link updated: http://madskristensen.net/post/web-essentials-2013-where-is-the-typescript-support (no .aspx suffix)

Answer (score 0):

Install the TypeScript for Visual Studio [plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790)
you will be able to see the JS code as soon as you save the TS file.
You can also debug the JS this way.

Answer (score 0):

The current Typescript plugin for VS2013 compiles only on save, not on build. This can be a pain if some typescript files are edited outside or if the project has to be rebuilt from scratch.

I added the following at the end of the csproj, in the `<Target Name="AfterBuild">` section.

```
<Exec Command="tsc.exe -target ES5 --sourcemap _core.ts"
    WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\js" />
```

where `js` is the directory where the typescript files are and _core.ts is the main typescript referencing all other typescripts in its header.

Now even if a co-workers fetches the project, it will automatically rebuild all javascript files.